# How can I share a workspace definition between multiple hosts?

Tags: perforce

I have created a Perforce workspace definition with which I will be able to "run the latest demo" on a PC.

Then I wanted to try and check out the same workspace on another PC in order to run the same demo. I found that I could not do this because the workspace is somehow tied to the first PC where I created it.

I ended up copying the workspace by

- inspecting the textual definition of the workspace and copying it to a text editor,
- searching and replacing "WantedWorkspaceName" with "WantedWorkspaceName_NewHostname",
- creating a new workspace with a new name ("WantedWorkspaceName_NewHostname"),
- giving the new workspace the same workspace root path ("D:\Demo") as the original workspace,
- pasting the modified textual representation into the textual representation of the new workspace.

Surely there must be a better way to achieve what I want? (Use the same workspace mapping on different hosts.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `-t template` option to `p4 client`:

```
p4 client -t WantedWorkspaceName WantedWorkspaceName_NewHostname
```

You may also want to look at streams, which are an alternative way of setting up client/branch mappings.  Rather than configuring each client individually, you define a single "stream" which encapsulates a set of depot mappings and branching relationships to other streams.  Then a client can be defined simply in terms of what stream it's associated with, and the views are auto-generated whenever the stream is changed.

Comment: The reason, incidentally, that client workspaces are tied to hosts via the `Host` field is that in the server db each client definition individually tracks all of the files in that client workspace.   
The server knows which files it's sent to which client, and it uses that information to optimize sync operations.  If a single client definition is getting synced to multiple client machines, it invalidates all that db state and messes up all your file operations; the `Host` check is a safety rail to keep you from getting into that situation.  (You can override/disable it, but you shouldn't!)

Comment: @ Samwise I appreciate very much how you not only give answers to my questions concerning Perforce but also explain backgrounds and alternatives. Thank you!